# How can I call a variable from another class in my Btn click event

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

How can I assign the UserInfo.getEmail() value into the variable email in the button click event?

## Admin Fragment

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            String email = "";
            fAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Password Reset link sent to your registered E-Mail!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to send reset email!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });

        }
    });

@Override
    public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot snapshot, int position) {
        UserInfo userInfo = snapshot.toObject(UserInfo.class);
        Log.d("Item_CLICK", "Clicked the item : " + position + "and the ID:" + userInfo.getEmail());

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private String email = "";
public void onClick(View v) {

            fAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Password Reset link sent to your registered E-Mail!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to send reset email!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });

        }
    });

@Override
    public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot snapshot, int position) {
        UserInfo userInfo = snapshot.toObject(UserInfo.class);
        Log.d("Item_CLICK", "Clicked the item : " + position + "and the ID:" + userInfo.getEmail());
        this.email = userInfo.getEmail();
    }
```

Comment: ty i get it now. Thanks for u guidance.